# Writing binary file

Tags: java

How to Skip a line when Writing data back to binary file? For example, I want to let the char double and int to be separate line in binary file.

```
DataOutputStream o = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("sampleData.dat"));

for (int i = 0;i<counter;i++) {
    for (int j = 0;j<type.size();j++) {
        if (type.get(j).equals("char")) {
            o.writeChar(c.get(i));
        }
        if (type.get(j).equals("double")) {
            o.writeDouble(dou.get(i));
        }
        if (type.get(j).equals("int")) {
            o.writeInt(inte.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense: if you're writing a binary file, why would you care what line a given piece of data is on? Conversely, if you want your file to be human-readable, write the data as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you don't intend to write a binary file.
You just want to print numbers in separate lines.
Write them out as ascii characters in a text file and then you can use a new line character.
A new line character is interpreted as new line in a text file. It doesn't make sense to want to print a new line in a binary file.